# Why doesn't Beep function work on Windows 10

Tags: c, winapi, windows-10, beep

I'm having a problem with the Beep function programming in C with Dev C++.

I need a beep lasting for 25 ms and the code line I'm using is

```
Beep (1000, 25)
```

This works fine on Windows 8/8.1, I'm getting exactly what I want.
But when I run the same program on Windows 10, it does not beep! I tried to rise up the duration, and then I noticed that if it is 100ms or greater, it beeps...

Any ideas of what's going on?
Could this may be caused by something related to the hardware?

Comment: *"Could this may be caused by something releted to the hardware?"* That might be the case. According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/utilapiset/nf-utilapiset-beep "The Beep function was written specifically to emit a beep on that piece of hardware." and "[...] The result is that Beep did not work on all computers without the chip. This was okay because most developers had moved on to calling the MessageBeep function"

Comment: However starting from Windows 7 its behavior is _simulated_ using the sound card. A quick search shows that this 100 ms issue is pretty common, it might be a limitation on how this _simulation_ is implemented. If you need precise timing then you should avoid `Beep()` all together and if you don't then you should use `MessageBeep()` or `PlaySound()`. If you need fine control over generated waveform then you should use the `waveOut*()` family of functions.

Comment: Oh ok! Thank you! 
I need precise timing and also control over the frequency, so I think I'll use the waveOut funtion family as you suggest! 
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a limitation of Windows itself, I have this program which appears to work fine when given the arguments you describe in your question (although 25ms is a very short blip, it's still audible).

Granted it's compiled under Visual Studio 2019 but I don't think that would make a difference.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>

int errorExit(char *str) {
    std::cerr << str << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3)
        return errorExit("beep: Usage: beep <frequency> <duration-in-millisecs>");

    int freq = std::atoi(argv[1]);
    if ((freq < 37) || (freq > 32767))
        return errorExit("beep: Frequency must be 37-32767 inclusive");

    int duration = atoi(argv[2]);
    if ((duration < 1) || (duration > 10000))
        return errorExit("beep: Duration must be 1-10000 inclusive");

    Beep(freq, duration);

    return 0;
}
```

If you can't get it working at the frequencies and durations you need, you may want to look into something like `PlaySound`, which can use arbitrary audio files, not just simple beeps. Then put your simple beeps into an audio file (using Audacity or some other tool) and play them.